Wifi 5GHz connects but no internet
I connect to the 5GHz home wifi but I don't have internet.
I have an XPS-15-9500 with Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon.
I have Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi which is compatible with 5GHz networks.
The 5GHz wifi network works fine on my phone.
Actually it sometimes works briefly on my laptop but after 20-30 seconds it stops, failing to load anything else.
I have tested all 5GHz channels available on the router (36, 40, 44, 48) but none works.
Wifi  power saving is off.
I wonder if i need to replace the wifi card?
Or maybe i should use another linux kernel (current is 6.8.0-48-generic)?
I would be happy to provide more info and any help is appreciated.
In the meantime here are some more details about my laptop:
dodohjk@dodohjk-XPS-15-9500:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
  Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma
    base: Ubuntu 24.04 noble
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 15 9500 v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Dell model: 0RHXRG v: A03 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell
    v: 1.31.0 date: 07/08/2024
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 37.1 Wh (100.0%) condition: 37.1/84.3 Wh (44.0%)
    volts: 12.0 min: 11.4 model: BYD DELL M59JH07 status: full
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech MX Master 3S charge: 80%
    status: discharging
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: Intel Core i7-10750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Comet Lake rev: 2 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 800 min/max: 800/5000 cores: 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800
    4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800
    bogomips: 62399
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Dell driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-9.5 bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] vendor: Dell
    driver: nvidia v: 550.120 arch: Turing bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-3: Realtek Integrated_Webcam_HD driver: uvcvideo type: USB
    bus-ID: 1-11:4
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 3072x1920~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,nvidia,swrast platforms:
    active: x11,surfaceless,device inactive: gbm,wayland,device-2
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa
    v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2 glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel
    UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-48-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi vendor: Rivet Networks Dual Band
    Wi-Fi 6 Killer AX1650s 160MHz 2x2 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.3
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB
    bus-ID: 1-14:6
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 5.2 lmp-v: 11
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 322.15 GiB (33.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: 2300 NVMe 1024GB
    size: 953.87 GiB temp: 33.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 85.95 GiB used: 16.42 GiB (19.1%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 55.9 MiB (58.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-3: /home size: 557.03 GiB used: 305.68 GiB (54.9%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p8
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 7.63 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p9
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: 42.0 C sodimm: SODIMM C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): cpu: 0
Info:
  Memory: total: 16 GiB note: est. available: 15.37 GiB
    used: 3.97 GiB (25.8%)
  Processes: 361 Uptime: 45m Init: systemd target: graphical (5)
  Packages: 2130 Compilers: gcc: 13.2.0 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.21 inxi: 3.3.34

My router details
Brand: TP-link
Hardware Version:Archer VR400 v3 00000002
Firmware Version:1.5.0 0.9.1 v00a1.0 Build 220321 Rel.60385n

Here i share my network logs, however I started using an ethernet cable for wired connection. Now it seems like the 5ghz wifi is working properly... could the wire connection have resetted some settings?
dodohjk@dodohjk-XPS-15-9500:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9194] NetworkManager (version 1.46.0) is starting... (boot:53b4493f-f1e5-4383-8539-a13d9bab89d0)
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9198] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.c>
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9283] manager[0x5d71518c5d10]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9287] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9514] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9514] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "dodohjk-XPS-15-9500"
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9536] dns-mgr: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9548] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (d>
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9550] manager[0x5d71518c5d10]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9550] manager[0x5d71518c5d10]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9572] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin->
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9576] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-a>
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9595] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin->
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9644] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin>
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9648] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin->
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9650] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9651] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9651] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9670] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-settin>
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9671] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9671] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Nov 21 10:10:49 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183849.9674] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.5055] dhcp: init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.5056] manager: (lo): new Loopback device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.5063] device (lo): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'exter>
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.5065] device (lo): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'ex>
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.5070] device (lo): Activation: starting connection 'lo' (5a77e438-9957-4bee-af33-87df72e0d636)
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.5072] device (wlp0s20f3): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.5075] manager: (wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.5077] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7096] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7101] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7108] device (lo): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7110] device (lo): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7112] device (lo): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7118] device (lo): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7129] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7131] device (lo): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7133] device (lo): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7136] device (lo): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7479] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7479] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp0s20f3 created
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7481] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7482] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'e>
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7484] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-s>
Nov 21 10:10:50 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183850.7487] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'm>
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0961] policy: auto-activating connection 'Château Henri_5GHz' (fb7eb1f1-706e-4b06-bec6-58590c236c7a)
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0966] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'Château Henri_5GHz' (fb7eb1f1-706e-4b06-bec6-58590c2>
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0967] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0969] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0971] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0974] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Château Henri_5GHz' has security, but secrets are re>
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0974] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0976] sup-iface[b88d9609a00cfcb6,0,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0984] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0987] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0989] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Château Henri_5GHz' has security, and secrets exist.  >
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0999] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Château Henri_5GHz'
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0999] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0999] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0999] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0999] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.0999] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.1006] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.1006] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.1231] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.1231] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.1565] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.1565] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.1762] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.1762] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.3563] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.3563] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless >
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.3563] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.3564] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.3568] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.4139] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.138, acd pending
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.5539] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.138
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.5542] policy: set 'Château Henri_5GHz' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.5585] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.5597] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.5598] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.5600] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.5607] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.5610] manager: startup complete
Nov 21 10:10:54 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183854.9147] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 21 10:10:55 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183855.5688] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 21 10:11:15 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732183875.3571] agent-manager: agent[e9b977cf1a042204,:1.74/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered
Nov 21 10:17:22 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184242.4562] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Nov 21 10:17:22 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184242.5122] device (eth0): interface index 3 renamed iface from 'eth0' to 'enx0c3796884da4'
Nov 21 10:17:22 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184242.5183] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'ext>
Nov 21 10:17:22 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184242.5207] settings: (enx0c3796884da4): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Nov 21 10:17:40 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184260.8127] device (enx0c3796884da4): carrier: link connected
Nov 21 10:17:40 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184260.8131] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface->
Nov 21 10:17:40 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184260.8139] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (1094464b-a1ae-3c43-be74-0ef30b5f2a3e)
Nov 21 10:17:40 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184260.8145] device (enx0c3796884da4): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (1094464b-a1ae-3c43-be74-0>
Nov 21 10:17:40 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184260.8146] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed>
Nov 21 10:17:40 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184260.8150] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:17:40 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184260.8157] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:17:40 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184260.8162] dhcp4 (enx0c3796884da4): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 21 10:17:41 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184261.4687] dhcp4 (enx0c3796884da4): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.121, acd pending
Nov 21 10:17:41 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184261.6178] dhcp4 (enx0c3796884da4): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.121
Nov 21 10:17:41 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184261.6260] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 21 10:17:41 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184261.6447] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed>
Nov 21 10:17:41 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184261.6449] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'manage>
Nov 21 10:17:41 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184261.6453] device (enx0c3796884da4): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 21 10:17:41 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184261.7042] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enx0c3796884da4) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov 21 10:17:41 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184261.7296] device (enx0c3796884da4): conflict detected for IP address 192.168.1.121 with host F0:9E:4A:8C:34:0D
Nov 21 10:17:43 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184263.8103] dhcp6 (enx0c3796884da4): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 21 10:24:07 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184647.2284] device (enx0c3796884da4): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-sta>
Nov 21 10:24:07 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184647.2286] dhcp4 (enx0c3796884da4): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov 21 10:24:07 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184647.2286] dhcp4 (enx0c3796884da4): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 21 10:24:07 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184647.2286] dhcp4 (enx0c3796884da4): state changed no lease
Nov 21 10:24:07 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184647.2290] dhcp6 (enx0c3796884da4): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov 21 10:24:07 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184647.2290] dhcp6 (enx0c3796884da4): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 21 10:24:07 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184647.2290] dhcp6 (enx0c3796884da4): state changed no lease
Nov 21 10:24:07 dodohjk-XPS-15-9500 NetworkManager[1043]: <info>  [1732184647.2634] policy: set 'Château Henri_5GHz' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS


Do you have an internet modem/router combination?  If so, can you provide the brand/model as an edit?

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status.

Please try kernel 6.11.8 and latest firmware.
